# Why can't use `cv2.cv.BoxPoints` in OpenCV (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am a beginner in OpenCV. I want to make bounding box around my detected marker.

Can you tell me how can I do it with OpenCV (Python)?

I'm using Python 3.6.3 with openCV

```
box =np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(marker))
```

Output:

```
Error showing cv2.cv2 has no module cv
```

Comment: Can you post [a **complete** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Likely, the problem is not in this line, but in the definition of `cv2`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`cv2.cv.BoxPoints` was changed.

For OpenCV 3.x, use `cv2.boxPoints` instead.

---

For example：

```
>> import numpy as np
>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0-dev'

>>> cnt = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [2,0]])
>>> bbox = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
>>> pts = cv2.boxPoints(bbox)
>>> print(pts)
[[  9.99999940e-01   9.99999881e-01]
 [  5.96046448e-08   0.00000000e+00]
 [  9.99999940e-01  -9.99999881e-01]
 [  1.99999976e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```